# Change the updated timestamp for users

Tags: users

I have a custom module that do some processes after a user entity is updated. I need to just trigger a timestamp update so my module can act on them accordingly. I wrote a script that is going through all my ~350000 users and doing this :

```
$loaded_user = user_load($uid);
user_save($loaded_user);
```

While this is working, the process is taking too long to finish. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea about running this in a more efficient way:

```
<?php
  $loaded_user = user_load($uid);
  $user->changed' = time();

  field_attach_update('user', $user);
?>
```

I am not 100% sure if this is gonna work for your setup the way you want to, i.e. if the hook you implement in your module is going to be called (not enough information there).

Let me know and I can give you an updated answer.

Cheers

Comment: My hook acts on both user_save and user_update. Do you think this approach would still work?

Comment: Your question (timestamp update in an efficient way), may need to be updated. I have the feeling this is not what you are going for.
I believe your question should be: how to trigger my custom code for all users in my system? Please, correct me if I am wrong.
Which hook(s) do you use? _presave, _update?